# Sails.js with handlebars templating engine

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, sails.js

I am trying to get sails.js work with handlebars.

the error i get: The partial links could not be found

the steps i took:

`sudo npm install -g sails-generate-views-handlebars`
`sails new sails-lab --template=handlebars`

in config/views.js:
`engine: 'handlebars',
layout: false`

I use the current version of sails, v0.10.5.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your config/views.js

```
engine:   'handlebars',
layout:   'layouts/layout',
partials: 'partials'
```

Comment: To provide a good answer, could you please elaborate on why you would do this, what effect does it have and why the users code does not work, This will help people with this issue learn, thanks

Comment: This worked for me and as I understand it, the error is thrown because layout is initially set to `layouts/layout.handlebars` instead of `layouts/layout`. This causes sails to look for the template at `layouts/layout.handlebars.handlebars` due to the erroneous extension.